# Copy vehicle information from JSON list to relational database

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework

I am looking for suggestion to make my for loop iterate faster. With about 2000 rows of data. Below code is taking lot of time to run. So far I have followed various Stack Overflow answers. For example reducing db queries and using Bulk insert to improve EF performance. It just improved marginally.

```
List<VehicleApplication> vehicleApplicationList = new List<VehicleApplication>();
List<ProductVehicleApplication> productVehicleApplicationList = new List<ProductVehicleApplication>();

if (inventoryjson["InventoryItems"][0]["VehicleApplications"] != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < inventoryjson["InventoryItems"][0]["VehicleApplications"].Count(); i++)
    {
        //database vehDb = new database();
        VehicleApplication vehicleApplication = new VehicleApplication();
        vehicleApplication.CategoryName = inventoryjson["InventoryItems"][0]["VehicleApplications"][i]["CategoryName"].ToString();
        vehicleApplication.MakeName = inventoryjson["InventoryItems"][0]["VehicleApplications"][i]["MakeName"].ToString();
        vehicleApplication.MfrLabel = inventoryjson["InventoryItems"][0]["VehicleApplications"][i]["MfrLabel"].ToString();
        vehicleApplication.ModelName = inventoryjson["InventoryItems"][0]["VehicleApplications"][i]["ModelName"].ToString();
        vehicleApplication.Note = inventoryjson["InventoryItems"][0]["VehicleApplications"][i]["Note"].ToString();
        vehicleApplication.PartTypeName = inventoryjson["InventoryItems"][0]["VehicleApplications"][i]["PartTypeName"].ToString();
        vehicleApplication.PositionName = inventoryjson["InventoryItems"][0]["VehicleApplications"][i]["PositionName"].ToString();
        vehicleApplication.Qty = inventoryjson["InventoryItems"][0]["VehicleApplications"][i]["Qty"].ToString();
        vehicleApplication.SubCategoryName = inventoryjson["InventoryItems"][0]["VehicleApplications"][i]["SubCategoryName"].ToString();
        vehicleApplication.YearID = inventoryjson["InventoryItems"][0]["VehicleApplications"][i]["YearID"].ToString();

        var existingVehicleApplication = dbVehiclesList.Where(x => x.MakeName == vehicleApplication.MakeName && x.ModelName == vehicleApplication.ModelName
            && x.CategoryName == vehicleApplication.CategoryName
            && x.MfrLabel == vehicleApplication.MfrLabel
            && x.PartTypeName == vehicleApplication.PartTypeName
            && x.PositionName == vehicleApplication.PositionName
            && x.Qty == vehicleApplication.Qty
            && x.YearID == vehicleApplication.YearID
            && x.SubCategoryName == vehicleApplication.SubCategoryName
            ).SingleOrDefault();

        if (existingVehicleApplication == null && vehicleApplicationList.Any(x => x.MakeName == vehicleApplication.MakeName && x.ModelName == vehicleApplication.ModelName && x.CategoryName == vehicleApplication.CategoryName && x.MfrLabel == vehicleApplication.MfrLabel && x.PartTypeName == vehicleApplication.PartTypeName && x.PositionName == vehicleApplication.PositionName && x.Qty == vehicleApplication.Qty && x.YearID == vehicleApplication.YearID && x.SubCategoryName == vehicleApplication.SubCategoryName) == false)
        {
            vehicleApplicationList.Add(vehicleApplication);
        }
        else
        {
            vehicleApplication = dbObj.VehicleApplication.SingleOrDefault(
            x => x.MakeName == vehicleApplication.MakeName
            && x.ModelName == vehicleApplication.ModelName
            && x.CategoryName == vehicleApplication.CategoryName
            && x.MfrLabel == vehicleApplication.MfrLabel
            && x.PartTypeName == vehicleApplication.PartTypeName
            && x.PositionName == vehicleApplication.PositionName
            && x.Qty == vehicleApplication.Qty
            && x.SubCategoryName == vehicleApplication.SubCategoryName
            && x.YearID == vehicleApplication.YearID);
        }

        ProductVehicleApplication productVehicleApplication = new ProductVehicleApplication();
        productVehicleApplication.Product = dbObj.Product.Single(x => x.Id == product.Id);
        productVehicleApplication.VehicleApplication = vehicleApplication;
        productVehicleApplicationList.Add(productVehicleApplication);
    }
}

dbObj.BulkInsert(productVehicleApplicationList);
dbObj.BulkInsert(vehicleApplicationList);
dbObj.SaveChanges();
```

UPDATE::1
From comments I have tried following. But it is still slow.

````
HashSet<VehicleApplication> vehicleApplicationList = new HashSet<VehicleApplication>();
                List<ProductVehicleApplication> productVehicleApplicationList = new List<ProductVehicleApplication>();
                if (jsonProduct["VehicleApplications"] != null)
                {
                 for (int i = 0; i < jsonProduct["VehicleApplications"].Count(); i++){
                            var vehicleApp = jsonProduct["VehicleApplications"][i];

                            VehicleApplication vehicleApplication = new VehicleApplication();
                            vehicleApplication.CategoryName = vehicleApp["CategoryName"].ToString();
                            vehicleApplication.MakeName = vehicleApp["MakeName"].ToString();
                            vehicleApplication.MfrLabel = vehicleApp["MfrLabel"].ToString();
                            vehicleApplication.ModelName = vehicleApp["ModelName"].ToString();
                            vehicleApplication.Note = vehicleApp["Note"].ToString();
                            vehicleApplication.PartTypeName = vehicleApp["PartTypeName"].ToString();
                            vehicleApplication.PositionName = vehicleApp["PositionName"].ToString();
                            vehicleApplication.Qty = vehicleApp["Qty"].ToString();
                            vehicleApplication.SubCategoryName = vehicleApp["SubCategoryName"].ToString();
                            vehicleApplication.YearID = vehicleApp["YearID"].ToString();


                            var existingVehicleApplication = dbVehiclesList.Where(x => x.MakeName == vehicleApplication.MakeName && x.ModelName == vehicleApplication.ModelName 
                                && x.CategoryName == vehicleApplication.CategoryName
                                && x.MfrLabel == vehicleApplication.MfrLabel
                                && x.PartTypeName == vehicleApplication.PartTypeName
                                && x.PositionName == vehicleApplication.PositionName
                                && x.Qty == vehicleApplication.Qty
                                && x.YearID == vehicleApplication.YearID
                                && x.SubCategoryName == vehicleApplication.SubCategoryName
                                ).SingleOrDefault(); 
                                
                    

                            if (existingVehicleApplication == null && vehicleApplicationList.Any(x => x.MakeName == vehicleApplication.MakeName && x.ModelName == vehicleApplication.ModelName && x.CategoryName == vehicleApplication.CategoryName && x.MfrLabel == vehicleApplication.MfrLabel && x.PartTypeName == vehicleApplication.PartTypeName && x.PositionName == vehicleApplication.PositionName && x.Qty == vehicleApplication.Qty && x.YearID == vehicleApplication.YearID && x.SubCategoryName == vehicleApplication.SubCategoryName) == false)
                            {
                                vehicleApplicationList.Add(vehicleApplication);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                vehicleApplication = existingVehicleApplication;
                                //vehicleApplication = dbVehiclesList.SingleOrDefault(
                                //x => x.MakeName == vehicleApplication.MakeName
                                //&& x.ModelName == vehicleApplication.ModelName
                                //&& x.CategoryName == vehicleApplication.CategoryName
                                //&& x.MfrLabel == vehicleApplication.MfrLabel
                                //&& x.PartTypeName == vehicleApplication.PartTypeName
                                //&& x.PositionName == vehicleApplication.PositionName
                                //&& x.Qty == vehicleApplication.Qty
                                //&& x.SubCategoryName == vehicleApplication.SubCategoryName
                                //&& x.YearID == vehicleApplication.YearID);

                            }

                            ProductVehicleApplication productVehicleApplication = new ProductVehicleApplication();
                            productVehicleApplication.Product = dbProductList.Single(x=>x.Id==product.Id);
                            productVehicleApplication.VehicleApplication = vehicleApplication;


                            productVehicleApplicationList.Add(productVehicleApplication);
                        }
                    }

                    dbObj.BulkInsert(productVehicleApplicationList);
                    dbObj.BulkInsert(vehicleApplicationList);
                    dbObj.SaveChanges();
```
````

Comment: I changed the title so that it describes what I think it does, per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.  The question is still lacking a lot of context needed for a decent review: the database schema and sample inputs, for starters.  Please [edit] to add the necessary information.  (Sorry I'm no expert in this language, so I'll still be unable to answer).

Comment: Wow title make lot of sense now. My poor english :(

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. We are different than Stack Overflow, we need to see more of the code because we are trying to help you improve the code rather than debug whatever problem you are having. We need to see whole functions, and it would be better to see complete classes. Optimization is a case of finding bottlenecks in some cases.

Comment: Everything that could be done in the DB should be. Dump the "raw" objects to the DB and then do all the iteration and transformation. Probably require temp tables with pseudo-keys?  In our case it went from 3+ hours of C#-cum-database to 15 seconds of a modestly complex stored procedure. Don't be afraid to create as many keys, compound-keys, unique columns as needed.  All that up-front set up is nothing; any decent relational DB engine is light-speed faster than C#. Make them permanent tables if this process is done regularly.

Answer (score 2):

`jsonProduct["VehicleApplications"].Count()` should be outside the iteration, otherwise it will be executed on each iteration which impact the performance. So, you should do :

```
var count = jsonProduct["VehicleApplications"].Count();

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var vehicleApp = jsonProduct["VehicleApplications"][i];
    ///...... etc.
}
```

using `SingleOrDefault` is slower than `FirstOrDefault` and that's because of their behavior. `SingleOrDefault` will recheck the enumerable against the founded item, to see if there is any duplicates, while `FirstOrDefault` doesn't do this check. In your case, you don't need to check the enumerable, you need to get the first item that matches the condition. So, using `FirstOrDefault` would be better choice.

also, when you use `HashSet` you don't really need to recheck the set for duplicates when adding items, as the `HashSet` will take care of that, and will always store unique items.  So, if you try to add an item that is already exists in the `HashSet`, it won't be added nor change the existing one.

try this version and see how it perform :

```
var vehicleApplications = jsonProduct["VehicleApplications"]; 

if(vehicleApplications != null)
{
    HashSet<VehicleApplication> vehicleApplicationHashSet = new HashSet<VehicleApplication>();
    
    List<ProductVehicleApplication> productVehicleApplicationList = new List<ProductVehicleApplication>();

    var count = vehicleApplications.Count();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var vehicleApp = jsonProduct["VehicleApplications"][i];

        VehicleApplication vehicleApplication = new VehicleApplication
        {
            CategoryName = vehicleApp["CategoryName"].ToString(),
            MakeName = vehicleApp["MakeName"].ToString(),
            MfrLabel = vehicleApp["MfrLabel"].ToString(),
            ModelName = vehicleApp["ModelName"].ToString(),
            Note = vehicleApp["Note"].ToString(),
            PartTypeName = vehicleApp["PartTypeName"].ToString(),
            PositionName = vehicleApp["PositionName"].ToString(),
            Qty = vehicleApp["Qty"].ToString(),
            SubCategoryName = vehicleApp["SubCategoryName"].ToString(),
            YearID = vehicleApp["YearID"].ToString()
        };
        
        var existingVehicleApplication = dbVehiclesList.FirstOrDefault(x =>
               x.MakeName == vehicleApplication.MakeName 
            && x.ModelName == vehicleApplication.ModelName 
            && x.CategoryName == vehicleApplication.CategoryName
            && x.MfrLabel == vehicleApplication.MfrLabel
            && x.PartTypeName == vehicleApplication.PartTypeName
            && x.PositionName == vehicleApplication.PositionName
            && x.Qty == vehicleApplication.Qty
            && x.YearID == vehicleApplication.YearID
            && x.SubCategoryName == vehicleApplication.SubCategoryName); 
        
        if(existingVehicleApplication != null)
        {
            vehicleApplication = existingVehicleApplication;
        }
        else
        {
            // if the vehicleApp is already in the hashset, then it'll not be added.
            vehicleApplicationHashSet.Add(vehicleApplication);
        }
        
        ProductVehicleApplication productVehicleApplication = new ProductVehicleApplication
        {
            Product = dbProductList.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id==product.Id),
            VehicleApplication = vehicleApplication
        };
        
        productVehicleApplicationList.Add(productVehicleApplication);
    }

    dbObj.BulkInsert(productVehicleApplicationList);
    dbObj.BulkInsert(vehicleApplicationList);
    dbObj.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: It does help me a little improvement but 
var existingVehicleApplication = dbVehiclesList.FirstOrDefault Querying against database 
as dbVehiclesList is AsEnumerable 

dbProductList.FirstOrDefault same case here. 

Is that possible that I get data from these tables into a very fast variable so I dont have to db query?

Comment: @JaskaranSingh what ORM are you using? because entity framework does not need t o cast as AsEnumerable ..